# mysql count rows from two tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have two MySQL-tables:
`Persons (pid,name,companyID,companyName)`
`Orders (oid,companyID,details)`

Now I want to count the number of order_id for each companyName as following:

```
Name         Total
-------------------
CompanyName1 : 1200

CompanyName2 : 758

CompanyName3 : 11
```

I used this query but it's not working properly.

```
SELECT count(o.oid) as total,p.companyName
    FROM orders as o, persons as p 
    WHERE o.companyID = p.companyID 
    GROUP BY p.companyName
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Why would a table called `orders` be joined to a table called `persons` using columns called `companyid`?  Something is wrong with your query.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` and group the result by `p.companyID`

```
 SELECT p.companyName, count(o.oid) as total
    FROM orders as o join persons as p
    on o.companyID = p.companyID
    GROUP BY p.companyID
```

Comment: Thank you @Bharat but I tried code query which return wrong data as well, it seems something is missing

Comment: @P.Coder could you please share the result you are getting?

Comment: Your query does not return a different result that the one of the OP. Also if you group by CompanyID but select companyName that only works in MySQL if a specific setting is active and is also bad practice.

Comment: @juergen d Could you please share the GOOD practice query?

Comment: Thanks for the info/correction @juergend. Could you please share the revised query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the companies without any orders you can use a `left join`.

```
SELECT p.companyName, count(*) as total
FROM persons p 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.companyID = p.companyID
GROUP BY p.companyID, p.companyName
```

Please do not use the old, legacy join syntax any more - it is outdated since 1992.

Comment: @p.coder: Don't you have a company table?

Comment: No company table.

Comment: The query don't group by the companyName as requested. you may see the result screenshot at https://justpaste.it/3qn46 ( PS: the ? is a company name example)

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your data. But since I cannot see complete example data I cannot help you any more.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I think the wrong result is happing because of the two tables have duplicate values of p.companyID

Answer (score 0):

Your data model looks messed up.  That you have company ids and names in the `person` table but no corresponding `companies` table is highly suspicious.

In any case, presumably there can be multiple rows per company.  You can condense the persons table and then `join`:

```
SELECT c.companyName, COUNT(*) as total
FROM orders o JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT companyId, companyName
      FROM persons p 
     ) c
     ON o.companyID = c.companyID 
GROUP BY c.companyName;
```

However, you should fix the data model so you have a real *bona fide* companies table -- especially because you seem to care about that entity.